# UL/LI CSS code not displaying top menu correctly

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am having an error with getting my top menu to work now that I have tried to use ul and li tags instead of divs. I have a ul with six li tags in it. I want each li tag to contain an image that should have the same dimensions as each other image. Each li tag image should horizontally take up just under 1/6 of the page. Vertically they should be about 100 px. I currently can not get the images to display properly. Even though I am using the same test image, all the separate tags are rendering differently.

Here is my CSS, HTML, and the images used in an Imgur link:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/raw/EbyXvXEg

CSS: http://pastebin.com/raw/P8nkGHxN

Imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCUC1.jpg

I can not get the menu to work as I want. The middle menu items are always displaying a larger or smaller picture. I can not get this to work. Could someone help point me in the direction of help at least? I am unsure how to get images to work in a jsfiddle or else I would post that.

Comment: Could you do a jsfiddle? Just link to where the image is on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add jour pictures as background of the a tags. Also aply your styling to a tags.

```
a {
    width: 16.66%;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background: url(your image URL);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: none;
}
```

background-size: cover; stretches the image until it fills your content box. You can also use images with different sizes.